# Index Type.Relationship value from KeystoneJS into elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, keystonejs, mongoosastic

I'm new to KeystoneJs and I want to index a `Type.Relationship` in elasticsearch using mongoosastic. The issue is in Mongo data of `Type.Relationship` is stored as an array of ObjectIDs - not the value of the actual relationship - as there may be multiple of each (see `categories` and `platform` below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d49e8ebe469b9614119259"),
    "slug" : "philips-hue",
    "title" : "Philips Hue",
    "categories" : [ 
        ObjectId("56d4a03abe469b961411925a"), 
        ObjectId("56d4a047be469b961411925b")
    ],
    "state" : "published",
    "__v" : 3,
    "author" : ObjectId("56d499ad995a533813adef63"),
    "publishedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-29T13:00:00.000Z"),
    "manufacturer" : ObjectId("56d5eeec1ffcbb0517f07e1b"),
    "platform" : [ 
        ObjectId("56d5ee0ab85dbdf916007009"), 
        ObjectId("56d5ee37b85dbdf91600700a"),
        ObjectId("56d5ee34uj3i223io23h2394")
    ]
}
```

These `ObjectId`s of `platform` are of format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d5ee0ab85dbdf916007009"),
    "key" : "homekit",
    "name" : "Homekit",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Can anyone put me on the right path to add to the elastic search index `name` of the ObjectIds that are referenced?

Comment: i am facing same issue. is your problem solved?